# Trying to figure out why wpdb is not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to run some `$wpdb` queries from the wp-admin.

Running them in code that runs on a wp-admin page.  And let me say - I have run this code successfully at several hosts from a wp-admin page.  So - I know the code works.

This is my question:

I am now at a host where this code does not work.  And I have determined that `$wpdb` is not working. The host support team tried to say it was because the version of PHP does not support "globalizing" wpdb...

Which I am pretty sure is BS...

So - my question to all of you is...can any of you think of other reasons why a $wpdb query would not work when run on a wp-admin page?

Thanks so much, Gerard

Comment: not sure myself but might be worth posting the php and mysql versions of the different hosting accounts, have you tried looking at the log files aswell?

Comment: What do your error logs say? ...do you get any errors at all (either PHP or MySQL errors)?

Comment: well - mixed in the code is some other code that opens a mysql database (seperate form wordpress database) and does queries on that as well; and the error logs show that it was looking for the wordpress tables in the mysql datbase and not the wordpress database; for example it was looking for wp_posts in the mysql database; now i have ran this same code at other hosts and it never did that; it always found the wp table just fine where it should; but now for some reason it is trying to find them in the mysql datbase; the only thing that makes sense to me is that $wpdb itself is not working...